# I cant load in Json file in python

Tags: python, json

I have this sample json file but Im unable to wor with the keys from my json file.

```
import json

people_string = """
{"widget": {
    "debug": "on",
    "window": {
        "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
        "name": "main_window",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500
    },
    "image": {
        "src": "Images/Sun.png",
        "name": "sun1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 250,
        "alignment": "center"
    },
    "text": {
        "data": "Click Here",
        "size": 36,
        "style": "bold",
        "name": "text1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 100,
        "alignment": "center",
        "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
    }
}}

"""
x = json.loads(people_string)
#print(x)
#print(type(x))

for a in x["widget"]:
    print(a)
```

When I run this code i get as output:

```
debug
window
image
text
```

How can I access from "window": "title"?

I tried

```
for a in x['widget']:
    print(a["window"])
```

but this gives me an error

Comment: `print(x["widget"]["window"]["title"])`

Comment: thanks dude this worked;)

Answer (score 0):

After json.loads() it is a nested dictionary.

Nested Dictionary: Nesting Dictionary means putting a dictionary inside another dictionary. Nesting is of great use as the kind of information we can model in programs is expanded greatly.

```
# Nested dictionary having same keys 
Dict = { 'Dict1': {'name': 'Ali', 'age': '19'}, 

         'Dict2': {'name': 'Bob', 'age': '25'}} 

  
# Prints value corresponding to key 'name' in Dict1 

print(Dict['Dict1']['name']) 


# Prints value corresponding to key 'age' in Dict2 

print(Dict['Dict2']['age'])
```

Answer (score 0):

After loading the json you can access both keys and values using `.items()`.

Example:

```
x = json.loads(people_string)

for key, value in x["widget"].items():
    print(key, value)
```

Output:

```
debug on
window {'title': 'Sample Konfabulator Widget',
    'name': 'main_window',
    'width': 500,
    'height': 500
}
image {'src': 'Images/Sun.png',
    'name': 'sun1',
    'hOffset': 250,
    'vOffset': 250,
    'alignment': 'center'
}
text {'data': 'Click Here', 
    'size': 36,
    'style': 'bold',
    'name': 'text1',
    'hOffset': 250,
    'vOffset': 100,
    'alignment': 'center',
    'onMouseUp': 'sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;'
}
```